# Como receber uma lista de Strings em um select do Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, java-ee

Eu tenho um select na minha página que deve ter seu valor e sua legenda populados através de uma lista de Strings que vêm da minha Action.

Estou enviando a lista corretamente, pois vejo a combo ter o número de elementos do mesmo tamanho que a lista, mas não sei como identificar o valor e a descrição na TagLib.

```
<s:select name="status" list="status" headerKey="" headerValue="-- Selecione --" id="statusMedico" listKey="" listValue="" />
```

O que eu devo utilizar em `listKey` e `listValue` para popular as options?

**O método na action:**

```
public List<String> getStatus() {
    return Arrays.asList("Ativo", "Inativo");
}
```

Comment: Não entendo muito de struts. Veja se este link te ajuda: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/. Esse japa é fera.

Comment: Obrigado, @EdgarMunizBerlinck. Mas a resposta é só tirar os atributos `listKey` e `listValue`.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta para esta pergunta é tirar os atributos `listKey` e `listValue`.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789972/struts2-how-to-populate-a-select-tag-with-a-list-of-string/21790165#21790165